# How do I disallow specific page from robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I am creating two pages on my site that are very similar but serve different purposes. One is to thank users for leaving a comment and the other is to encourage users to subscribe.

I don't want the duplicate content but I do want the pages to be available. Can I set the sitemap to hide one? Would I do this in the robots.txt file?

The disallow looks like this:

Disallow: /wp-admin

How would I customize to the a specific page like:

http://sweatingthebigstuff.com/thank-you-for-commenting

Answer (score 61):

```
Disallow: /thank-you-for-commenting$
```

in **robots.txt**

Take a look at [last.fm robots.txt file](http://www.last.fm/robots.txt) for inspiration.

The dollar sign marks an end. We need that so other pages starting with the same url, for example /thank-you-for-commenting-another-page, will be indexed.

Comment: I'm relieved someone had the foresight to disallow harm to humans.

Comment: Surely this will suffer false positives, because the standard says "any URL that starts with this value will not be retrieved".

Comment: edited this answer so a $ sign and explanation is included

Answer (score 14):

robots.txt files use regular expressions to match pages, so to avoid targeting more pages than you intend, you may need to add a $ to the end of the page name:

```
Disallow: /thank-you-for-commenting$
```

If you don't you'll also disallow page /thank-you-for-commenting-on-this-too

Answer (score 10):

You can also add a specific page with extension in **robots.txt** file.  In case of testing, you can specify the test page path to disallow robots from crawling.

For examples:

```
 Disallow: /index_test.php
 Disallow: /products/test_product.html
 Disallow: /products/
```

The first one `Disallow: /index_test.php` will disallow bots from crawling the test page in root folder.

Second `Disallow: /products/test_product.html` will disallow test_product.html under the folder 'products'.

Finally the last example `Disallow: /products/` will disallow the whole folder from crawling.