# Laravel search engine debug pages

Tags: laravel

I need to prevent search engine from indexing my error pages (debug pages) .
yes i know about 
 `APP_DEBUG=false` 
 to stop showing the error but i wondering if there is method to prevent search engine entirely from indexing this pages in case if someone forgot about stop debugging mode.
thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486458/how-do-i-disallow-specific-page-from-robots-txt)

robots.txt is used to do such tasks

Comment: thanks but this is not what i looking for ; i thought that there is method in Laravel itself to prevent search engine to index this pages by adding no follow meta to it or something like that.